# iphone x home indicator issue while using tableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, iphone-x, xcode9.1

I have some doubts. I'm using a `UITableViewController`, and at bottom it's not giving space for the home indicator. It goes behind the home indicator (refer to the image). If I add any button actions to the last `cell`, this will surely cause an error.

[image: iphone x home indicator issue whle using tableViewController]

Comment: have you set the bottom space relative to the safe area?

Comment: as it was UITableViewController we cant set the bottom space right

Comment: In TableViewController, When you scroll to last row, your cell content wont' clip with home indicator.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this to add programmatically... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area

Answer (score 0):

Use Safe area layout constraints. See the attachment bellow.Your problem will be solved.

[image]

Comment: This your answer resolve the issue when we use any UIView or UITableView. but in my case im using UITableViewController. I cant give any constraints to it.